# how to find combinations present in different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataset with sample and shop names. I am trying to figure out a way to calculate proportion of shops that sell a combination of samples. For example, sample 12,13 and 22 are available in shop2,3 and 4. Like wise, sample6,7,8,9,10, 16 and 17 is available in shop1.
The dataset i have is very large with 9000 columns and 26 rows. Here what i show is just a small dataset. What i want to do is to figure a way to screen the table for all possible combination of samples present in shops (if >0) and print out in a dictionary, for example sample12_sample13_sample22:[shop2,shop3,shop4] and List out all possible combinations that are available.

Sorry that I could not figure out how to do this, so i do not have any code, right now.
What approach should i use here?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Name    Shop1   Shop2   Shop3   Shop4

Sample1 0       0       0       0

Sample2 0       0       0       0

Sample3 0       0       0       0

Sample4 0       0       0       0

Sample5 0       0       0       0

Sample6 1       0       0       0

Sample7 4       0       0       0

Sample8 12      0       0       0

Sample9 1       0       0       0

Sample10        1       0       0       0

Sample11        0       0       0       0

Sample12        0       5       21      233

Sample13        0       8       36      397

Sample14        0       4       0       0

Sample15        0       0       0       0

Sample16        2       0       0       0

Sample17        17      0       0       0

Sample18        0       0       0       0

Sample19        0       0       0       0

Sample20        0       0       0       0

Sample21        0       0       0       0

Sample22        0       1       20      127
```

Comment: Please do not post pic for your sample df

Comment: Sorry i could add the data as a table. How do i do that?

Comment: Just do copy paste ~

Comment: Thanks! Is that fine?

Answer (score 0):

What we can do is `melt` then we `groupby` twice

```
s = df.melt('Name')
s = s[s.value!=0]
s = s.groupby('Name')['variable'].agg([','.join,'count'])
out = s[s['count']>1].reset_index().groupby('join')['Name'].agg(','.join)
out
Out[104]: 
join
Shop2,Shop3,Shop4    Sample12,Sample13,Sample22
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick answer! I will try your suggestion and check if i get the results as i wanted.